# How can I add gpus to an running Docker container?

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

I am running a `nvidia-docker` container with the initial flag `--gpus="device=0"` and now I would like to add the second device to the **running** container. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This should help you: https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/user-guide.html

Comment: The question is for adding an addition GPU device to a running container. In the docs they show nicely how to run a container with the nvidia-runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1211), it's not possible.

A possible workaround:

I ran into a similar situation, where I had set up a development environment, but I forgot to add the `--gpus all` option. Since I didn't want to lose my work, my workaround was to commit the container to an image using

```
docker commit <running_container> <image_name>
```

and then run the new image with the `--gpus all` option

```
docker run -it [...] --gpus all --name <new_container_name> <image_name>
```